# How I insert new line in listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert new line 
after adding some controls in listview 
but I dont know how with c# code

```
userListViewDetails.Controls.Add(NEW LINE);
```

Comment: Please learn HTML. HTML does not have "newlines".

Comment: you want an empty space in list view or a new item?

Comment: empty space like "\n" just in listview

Comment: here new line is not a control to add in list view using userListViewDetails.Controls.Add(NEW LINE);

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add another control that will simply display a new line (such as a label or literal).  You would then just set the text of this object to "
", since your output is going to be html.  You may want to post a little more of your code just so it would be easier to understand what you're trying to do.